# How to make a hideable sidenav have a correct scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I've built a menu using the code from this W3schools example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push

If I have little content in the left menu, it is fine. But I have more content than fits in the window. Therefor:

- the scrollbar doesn't allow to see all elements: it stops before the end
- we don't even see the lower part of the scrollbar

How can I fix the CSS to see all content in the menu?

```js
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "500px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "500px";
}

function closeMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

openMenu();
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.middle {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}



/* ----- MENU CONTENT ----- */

.closebtn {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menuContent {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive;font-family: 'Princess Sofia', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>RFC5 Atlas</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rouge+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Princess+Sofia&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openMenu()">LOGO IMAGE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div id="menu" class="menu">
                <div class="menuContent">
                    <h1>Title h1</h1>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>
                    
                    <h2>Title h2 - 1</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 2</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 3</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 4</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 5</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 6</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 7</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 8</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 9</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 11</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 12</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 13</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 14</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 15</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 16</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776; menu</span>
                <div id="mapBody"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `height: 100%` for the menu and `padding-top: 100px` for `.middle`, the container of the menu. The padding is pushing the 100% height menu downwards so that it has an overflow at the bottom of 100px. Therefor you have to subtract the padding from the 100% height. This can be done with the CSS `calc()` function. Furthermore you should declare the `padding-top` as `margin-top` and give all elements a `box-sizing: border-box`.

**Working example**:

```js
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "500px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "500px";
}

function closeMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

openMenu();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.middle {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.menu {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}



/* ----- MENU CONTENT ----- */

.closebtn {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menuContent {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive;font-family: 'Princess Sofia', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>RFC5 Atlas</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rouge+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Princess+Sofia&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openMenu()">LOGO IMAGE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div id="menu" class="menu">
                <div class="menuContent">
                    <h1>Title h1</h1>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>
                    
                    <h2>Title h2 - 1</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 2</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 3</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 4</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 5</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 6</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 7</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 8</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 9</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 11</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 12</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 13</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 14</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 15</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 16</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776; menu</span>
                <div id="mapBody"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also should put the margin-top of body to 0 and consider the padding-top 10px of menu, then the bottom of the scrollbar appears.